# capture update membership status hook from admin memberships panel

Tags: wordpress, hook, woocommerce-memberships

I'm working on a woocommerce plugin, an extension for woocommerce memberships. I need to capture the hook which is fired when the status of the membership change.

So I try to use `wc_memberships_user_membership_status_changed` but it won't fire when the change comes to admin panel.
I suppose that it fires when the status changes naturally when it becomes expired for example.

**CODE SAMPLE**

```
function membershipuser_status_changed($user_membership, $old_status, $new_status ){
  error_log('wc_memberships_user_membership_status_changed');
}
add_action( 'wc_memberships_user_membership_status_changed', 'membershipuser_status_changed', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check using "transition_post_status" hook

```
function some_function( $new, $old, $post ) {
    if ( $post->post_type == 'your_post_type' ) {
        // do stuff
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

Source: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/transition_post_status/